# syncing facebook friends with Contacts - Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, contacts

Facebook and Twitter made a sync option to sync my contacts list with my friends, so when I click on one of my synced contacts from the regular phone app, I get to see their last status, pictures, etc.

I would like to use this data from fb and twitter instead of building the sync process on my own, for both fb and twitter. because they already built it and me doing this again is inefficient.

Can I find it in ContactsContract (the same database of my contacts)? if yes, then where?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook imported or sync'd contacts data isn't accessible unless the user on the phone has contacted that person from their phone, imported that person from gmail previously or manually had put in the data prior to the facebook data sync.

You can test this by brute forcing the Contacts._ID and iterating through the ones that don't get returned in a standard query... you will have an exception thrown but after you contact a particular person the data will be accessible.